# How to convert format long value 20010203 to string 2001-02-03?

Tags: c++, string, date, type-conversion

I have variable long. Example:

```
long date = 20010203;
```

I need to print value by cout in this format 2001-02-03.Example:

```
cout << "Today is " << "2001-02-03" << endl;
```

I need to convert value long 20010203 to string format with "-" for print. How to do?
I only can use these libraries:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: When is the homework due?  Look at the standard C string functions available via `cstring`, there a million tutorials around.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/?kw=cstring cstring has't functions for convert from integer to string. What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way would be:

```
long year = date / 10000;
long month = (date - (year * 10000)) / 100;
long day = (date - (year * 10000) - (month * 100));

std::cout << "Today is " << year << "-" << (month < 10 ? "0" : "") << month << "-" << (day < 10 ? "0" : "") << day << std::endl;;
```

Comment: but month and day has't zero before. 02 06 etc.

Comment: And? You just have to do a simple condition checking if your number is  inferior to 9 and displaying a zero before it if so...

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach, divide and truncate

20010203 / 10000000 = 2, now you have the first digit.

subtract ( 10000000 * 2 ) from 20010203 to get 0010203

Rinse and repeat Until you have all the necessary digits.

Edit, Me being Dumb

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    long date=20010203;
    char arr[9];
    sprintf(arr, "%ld", date);//converts long to string
    std::cout << "Today is ";
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        if(i==4 || i==6) std::cout << '-';
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```